# reverse engineering for FosUser Bundle

Tags: symfony, reverse-engineering

if you work with an existing database, and the database contains a user table that contains all the information from our user how we can make...
once i installed fosuserBundle he will create a new table fos_user..how can i merge my old data with the new data, or transfering the old data to the new data
Is it possible to do reverse,  engineering, if yes how ??
Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to adapt your existing user table to make it work with FosUser?

Comment: yes right !! how i can do that

Comment: What have you tried? Once you have installed FosUserBundle, your User class will inherit FosUSerBundle, you'll be able to add some properties (fields) to your User class if needed. Maybe your problem is transfering the old data to the new table?

Comment: once i installed fosuserBundle he will create a new table fos_user..how can i merge my old data with the new data, or transfering the old data to the new data

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Please edit your question to improve it, adding what you just said in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a similiar task to do for a couple of days, you just need to extend the FOSUserBundle User Entity with your UserEntity where you're going to add all the Columns you need that the BaseUser doesn't provide.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * user
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * 
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    //Here you can extend the BaseUser provided from the FOSUserBundle
    //with the Columns you need 
}
```

After that you just need to write a SQL Script with migrates the Data from the one Table to the new Table

```
INSERT INTO fos_user(`id`, `username`, `username_canonical`, `email`, `email_canonical`, `enabled`, `password`)
SELECT      `id`, `name`, `name`, `email`, `email`, `active`, `password` 
FROM        old_user_table;
```

This is the script i was using to do this datamigration. Just run it in phpmyadmin.

It is not necessary to add the *_canonical fields manually AFAIK, i'm just doing it to be safe.

Hope it helped.